# PHP max exec time ,max upload limit, memory limit etc to unlimited with 0 or -1

Tags: php, ini-set

Sorry if this type of ques already exists.

To set php ini values in script what is the better way for infinity purpose?
some people preferred -1 or some 0.

What's the best solution? And why?

Thanks

Comment: If set to zero, no time limit is imposed. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually that's a bad idea, especially max_exec_time and max_upload_limit - an open invitation to DOS ! And also memory_limit may help you protect your server against scripts running mad.

I wouldn't recommend to set those values to unlimited on a production server, and on stage and test it doesn't even make sense at all, unless you want to restart your server all the time after a programming error.